# Illegal option: androiddebugkey keytool -list [OPTION]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a SHA1 certificated fingerprint for a firebase app but I keep getting this error and I don't know why because I followed indeed the command I found.

[image: Error]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't share screenshots of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a space between `...debug.keystore"` and `-alias`.